# Transition Probabilities - Markov Process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose there is a box with $N$ balls. Each ball is coloured either red or blue. In each time period, one ball is chosen at random from the box and with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ replaced with the other colour; or the ball is returned to the box. Let $X_{n}$ denote the number of red balls after $n$ picks.

A) Determine the transition probabilities: $$p_{ij}, \forall{i,j}=0,1,....,N$$

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. If you have $x$ red balls after $n$ picks, what is the probability that your $(n+1)$th pick is red?
2. or blue?
3. What happens to the number of red balls in each of these cases?
4. If you have $x$ red balls after $n$ picks, what are the possible numbers of red balls after $n+1$ picks?
5. What are the probabilities that you transition to each of these possibilities?

Comment: okay so far for 1 i got $\frac{x}{N}$ and 2 i got $\frac{N-x}{N}$ and I have no idea what next.

Comment: @Reety You may be overthinking this as you have already done the heavy work. For example with question 3 the number of red balls goes down by $1$ if the $(n+1)$th pick was red, and up by $1$  if the $(n+1)$th pick was blue.  So for 4 the number of red balls becomes $x-1$ or $x+1$, and for 5 the respective probabilities of these are those you identified for 1 and 2; these are the transition probabilities as all others are $0$

Comment: $p_{ii}=\frac{1}{2}$, $p_{i(i-1)}=\frac{x}{N}$, $p_{i(i+1)}=\frac{N-x}{N}$ and $p_{ij}=0$ if |i-j|≥2 this is what I got

Comment: @Reety I think you should have $p_{ii}=0$ but otherwise that seems correct.  Perhaps better to write something like $p_{i,(i-1)}=\frac{i}{N}, p_{i,(i+1)}=\frac{N-i}{N}, p_{i,j}=0$ if $j \not=i\pm1$ as $x$ and $i$ represent the same thing